# What's the difference between OpenSSL and the native windows Secure Channel library

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to download git bash for my laptop recently and trying to decide what is the difference between the two options. Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are using git in an organization with enterprise-managed certificates, then you will need to use Secure Channel. If you are using git only to access public repositories (like GitHub) or your organization does not manage its own certificates, then you are perfectly fine using either SSL backend (they are just different implementations of the same protocol).

From https://github.com/git/git/commit/21084e84a418e0a6c4da72f632c5cd99386bd64b

> As of version 7.56.0, curl supports being compiled with multiple SSL
>   backends.
>
> This patch adds the Git side of that feature: by setting http.sslBackend
>   to "openssl" or "schannel", Git for Windows can now choose the SSL
>   backend at runtime.
>
> This comes in handy on Windows because Secure Channel ("schannel") is
>   the native solution, accessing the Windows Credential Store, thereby
>   allowing for enterprise-wide management of certificates. For historical
>   reasons, Git for Windows needs to support OpenSSL still, as it has
>   previously been the only supported SSL backend in Git for Windows for
>   almost a decade.
>
> The patch has been carried in Git for Windows for over a year, and is
>   considered mature.